# Relational algebra

Tags: foreign-keys, relational-algebra

Suppose R1(A*,B) and R2(C*,D) are two relation schemas. Let r1 and r2 be the corresponding relation instances. B is a foreign key that refers to C in R2. If data in r1 and r2 satisfy referential integrity constraints than will it be correct to say ∏ B (r1) - ∏ C (r2) = ∅ (even when one of the tuple in r1 contains null corresponding to the B attribute.)

Comment: ∏:This is Project operation.

Comment: May i ask, what is your question?

Comment: Does an asterisk indicate a prime attribute?

Answer (score 0):

> will it be correct to say ∏ B (r1) - ∏ C (r2) = ∅

In relational algebra (as typically defined), yes. But a justification depends on what definition of foreign key you are using.

> even when one of the tuple in r1 contains null

There are no nulls in relational algebra (as typically defined). They are from SQL. (Primary keys are also irrelevant to relational algebra; candidate keys matter.)

The notion of an SQL foreign key is different from the algebraic notion. First, it involves nulls. Second, an SQL PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE NOT NULL declaration declares a superkey, not necessarily a candidate key, and an SQL FOREIGN KEY declaration references a superkey, not necessarily a candidate key.